# Unity crashed ubuntu 11.10

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

So I installed compiz manager and ticked water effect or something, after that unity menu crashed and i can not enable it, unity 2D works fine 
 can some one help me to re enable unity